# jQuery Form Validator not behaving how I need it to for my class assignment

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am working on an assignment in my online Javascript class and I've already annoyed my teacher by asking too many questions so I am wondering if anyone here can help me. The assignment is that I have to use jQuery to validate a form but every time I try looking up a solution I encounter a bunch of confusing jargon that doesn't apply to what I am trying to accomplish. These are the plugins I am required to use that have been included in the html page:

http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js

http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/additional-methods.min.js

Using these plugins I have to validate a form for a hypothetical hotel reservation. The date is required and must be properly formatted (mm/dd/yyyy), there needs to be a number of nights that has to be an integer which must be positive but no more than 5, the email must follow a valid email address pattern, and the comment section is required. The html is already provided and I am not allowed to alter anything on the html page; I can only only make changes to the document using the jQuery in the .java file.

I have some code entered already but the validation isn't working how I want it to. 1/1/1 is being accepted as a valid date, the message I included for an invalid number of days is being overridden by the plugin's default messages and I can't find a way to specify a message for a negative integer, and nothing pops up to alert the user when there is nothing in the comment text field.

Whenever I search online for solutions to these problems I find a bunch of things I can't use because they aren't jquery or I simply don't understand what they're talking about. This is my first Javascript class and I was getting by just fine until this assignment. Here is the code I have which is not behaving properly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#reservation_form').validate({
debug: true,
rules: {
    arrival_date: {
        required: true,
        date: true 
        },
    nights: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 5
        },
    name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
        },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
        },
    comments: "required"
    },
message: {
    arrival_date: {
        required: "Arrival date is required",
        date: "Please include a valid date"
    },
    nights: {
        required: "Number of nights is required",
        number: "Please enter a positive integer",
        min: "Please en",
        max: "Cannot be more than 5 nights"
    },
    name: {
        required: "Name is required",
        minlength: "Name must be at least 2 characters long"
    },
    email: {
        required: "email is required",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    comments: "Please provide comments"
    }
});
}); // end ready
```

Please keep in mind that I am a beginner so I may need a simplified explanation for how to fix this problem. I'm sure for the experienced coders on this site the solution will be quick and easy, but I need it to be explained in language that I can understand so I can finally understand what I am doing and not need to ask these stupid questions again. Thank you in advance for taking pity on me!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/S7xBmLkXF539qygGlCwi?p=preview Please visit this simple example first then response back to me . thanks

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really help me because all it does is run the validate function, and I need to specify how I want the form validated using jQuery in the .java file. I'm required to give certain messages when the requirements aren't met but the messages I wrote are being overridden by the default messages in the plugins.

Comment: can you show me your code on plnkr.co then i can help you easily. Thanks

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/XPCqsRddlzp7vPd14zei?p=preview

Comment: you have missed many files Eg reservation.js ,main.css and html5.js .

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I've never used Plunker before so I have no idea how to do it or what I did wrong.